# How can I check if the user has entered valid value?

Tags: c++, struct, integer

I'm writing a project and I have to check if the user has entered a valid value for specific things. For example, first case is to check whether he inputted an integer, which is no longer than 6 length and >0. I am working with struct, so my code is this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int dolzina_int(int vlez);

int main()
{
    struct pole{
        int sifra;              // sifra na artiklot
        string opis;            // opis na artiklot
        float cena;             // edinecna cena
        int vlez_kol;           // vlezna kolicina
        int izlez_kol;          // izlezna kolicina
        float dan_stapka;       // danocna stapka
        float iznos;            // iznos
        int datum;              // datum na vlez i izlez (GGMMDD)
    }artikli[100];              // maksimalen broj na artikli e 100


    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){

        cin >> artikli[i].sifra;

        while(!(cin >> artikli[i].sifra) ||
              (artikli[i].sifra < 0 || (dolzina_int(artikli[i].sifra) > 6)))
            {
                cout << "Error" << endl;
                cin.clear();
                std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            }
        }


    return 0;
}

// funkcija za dolzina na integer
int dolzina_int(int vlez){
    int dolzina = 1;
    while(vlez > 0){
        dolzina++;
        vlez /= 10;
    }
    return dolzina;
}
```

So, my code seems to work, the first part, it does check if it's >6 or <0, but the second else if, it doesn't work properly to check if it's an integer or not. So my question is the following, how can i make sure that it's an integer value that the user enters and how can I make sure the length of integer is not >6 or the value is <0 and meanwhile, if it is, to make him re-enter it, and also check the newly entered value, as my code doesn't do that currently.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){

    artikli[i].sifra = 1;

    do{
        cout << "Enter a code: ";
        while(!(cin >> artikli[i].sifra)){
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore();
            cout << "Invalid entry. Enter a new value: ";
        }
    }while(artikli[i].sifra > 0 && dolzina_int(artikli[i].sifra) > 6);
}
```

Comment: I will try to help. Can you show me your class please and the entirety of your `main` function?

Comment: Updated the whole source code (current) in main post.

Comment: Thank you. I will try my best to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks. The language for variables is in my own native one, sorry about that, I just have a habit of doing that.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work *properly* to check if it's an integer"? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Like, if I type "aaa", it breaks the whole program, goes to the end instantly, instead of asking the user to type a new value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should note that the extraction will only succeed if the contents read from the file can be used as a correct value of the type of the object (in this case the integer `sifra`). If it doesn't work, `ios_base::failbit` will be set in the stream state.

So what needs to be done is that when an incorrect value is given, we discard the wrong text, clear the stream state, and re-try the extaction. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        while (!(std::cin >> artikli[i].sifra) ||
                ((artikli[i].sifra < 0) || (artikli[i].sifra > 6)))
        {
            std::cout << "Entered an incorrect value, try again.\n";
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to use struct and the program isn't finished fully, that's why it has so many variables, I've declared them for future use.

Comment: @user3002211 Even so, it is still idiomatic to use an inserter for user-defined classes.

Comment: I understand that it's pain in the ass to insert a lot of variables, however that's what the program requires (It's an exercise). As for the vectors part, I'm not allowed to use them :(.

Comment: @user3002211 Then just take the code from the inserter and use it in main (and use a regular array instead of the vector). Also, don't forget to change the name from `is` to `cin`.

Comment: @user3002211 I made an edit. Please try it again. It should work.

Comment: @user3002211 What I did was is switch the positions of `is.clear()` and `is.ignore(...)`. Is there anything you are still having trouble with?

Comment: Unfortunately, I've no idea what's going on in the code you wrote above... except the last one with vector example, which I can't use. The point of this exercise is to use structures / directories to make it work..

Comment: 3 errors. 1: `numeric_limits` is not a member of `std` 2: expressed primary-expression before `>` token. 3: no matching function for call to `max()`. All 3 on the same line `cin.ignore();`

Comment: @user3002211 Now try it. Let me know what happens.

Comment: @user3002211 Then you didn't copy-paste my entire program. It compiles without any errors for me.

Comment: @user3002211 let [us continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42078/discussion-between-0x499602d2-and-user3002211).

Answer (score 0):

First you should check this out:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/

Second, I think your over complicating it...

1) Read in int

2) check value of int

3) repeat

So I would do this

for (i = 0 to i < 5 add one to i)

while (entered value is not digit)

get digit until value is valid

Something like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   cout << "Enter the code" << endl;
   cin >> artikli[i].sifra;
   while(!is_digit) {
      cout << "Invalid, please repeat" << endl;
      cin >> artikli[i].sifra;
   }
}
```

Comment: My code is this: `while(!isdigit(artikli[i].sifra) && (dolzina_int(artikli[i].sifra) > 6) && (artikli[i].sifra) < 0){
            cin >> artikli[i].sifra;
        }` and when I run the program, it automatically fills the value and closes.

Comment: I don't get what your code is doing... You need to tell me what your functions do or even mean, because something like "sifra" doesn't tell me what it does.. Sorry I think we aren't specking english here.

Comment: Sorry, sifra means code in my language. Anyway, let's make the code simplier, `while(isdigit(artikli[i].sifra)){ cin >> artikli[i].sifra; }` then when I enter `aaa`, it automatically writes value for the rest of entries and closes the program, without allowing the user to correct the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to restrict your input to integers and have them in a specific `[min, max]` range, you would do it like this:

```
int input = -1;
do
{
    std::cout << "Enter a value in the range [min, max]:  ";
    while (!(std::cin >> input)) // while the input is invalid
    {
        std::cin.clear(); // clear the fail bit
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // ignore the invalid entry
        std::cout << "Invalid Entry!  Please Enter a valid value:  ";
    }
} while (min > input || max < input);
```

Where `min` and `max` are whatever values you are looking to keep the value between.

Comment: I want to check if the user entered an integer first of all, if he did, then I would like to check if it's bigger than 0, and if it's length is smaller or equal to 6. If so, then proceed to next, else re-enter a new integer.

Comment: If the type is an `int` (which `input` is here), the input will fail if you enter something else.  For example, if the user enters `a`, the fail bit will be set.  So there is no need to check if the input is an integer unless you are reading it in as a string.

Comment: I updated the code in the first post, check it out, using your method, it doesn't seem to work as intended. Even when I enter value <0, it doesn't display error, nor when the value has more than 6 digits inside. Also, there is some kind of error that allows me to loop more than 5 times.

Comment: @user3002211 If you enter a value outside the range (e.g. -1, 7, etc), the code above will not display an error message.  You can add that easily.  The code here is focused on reading in valid integers.  If you do not enter a valid integer within the range, it asks you to input again.  If you want 5 values, you would need to wrap this code with a loop that increments to 5.  I put you on the path, but I'm not going to do your homework for you.